# Moving widgets in window from QFileDialog library

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

Is it possible to move widgets in QFileDialog's window? Example during opening or saving file. I would like to make a space between file name's line edit and file type's combo box, so I need to move combo box one row lower. Is it possible to make modification like this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could give a clearer explanation, some images that illustrate what you want would help us understand you.

Comment: I added to my post, i marked it in red. I would like to make a space between file name and file type(between line edit and combo box too)

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want.

Comment: Shown, in this space i would like to put an extra widget example new line edit. I know how to add it, but dont know how to modificate window as in the picture

Comment: you are going the wrong way asking for adding a space, a more appropriate question is how to insert a QLabel with a QLineEdit in that space that you show. I am right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry if my question was unclear. I would like to put a widget there

Comment: should the widget occupy 1, 2 or 3 columns? considering as 1st column to QLabel, 2nd to QLineEdit and 3rd to QPushButton.

Comment: I would like to add it in first column

Comment: You could show me an image edit what you want, that is, the image with the widget you want to add.

Comment: If example i would like to copy label(file name), line edit and button "save" to this empty space? So in first column would be label, in second line edit and in third push button. Same as above. You know what i mean or add a picture?

Comment: You might set your own view delegate `QFileDialog::setItemDelegate(QAbstractItemDelegate *delegate)`

Comment: I will try it, thanks for help :)

Comment: @MohammadKanan The view delegate has to do with the view embedded in the dialog, not with any other controls.

Comment: @KubaOber, Hmm .. you mean listings of files ...etc.

Comment: @MohammadKanan Yes - the file listing is an embedded `QTreeView`.

Answer (score 1):

To do this requires modifications to the layout of the widgets that make up the `QFileDialog`. A complete example follows. You'd want to add your own content (widgets, layouts, etc.) into the freed-up space - the necessary details are returned from `modDialog`. The `SO::SpaceButtons` option takes the buttons out of the internal `QDialogButtonBox` and lays them out around the inserted row. Otherwise, the space extends only within the first two columns, and the button box remains unchanged.

[image: Screenshot of the modified file dialog]

```
// filedialog-mod-49371087
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <initializer_list>

struct GridPos {
   int row = -1, col = -1, rowSpan = {}, colSpan = {};
   GridPos(QGridLayout * layout, QWidget * widget) {
      int index = layout->indexOf(widget);
      if (index >= 0)
         layout->getItemPosition(index, &row, &col, &rowSpan, &colSpan);
   }
   GridPos(int r, int c, int rs, int cs) : row(r), col(c), rowSpan(rs), colSpan(cs) {}
   bool operator==(const GridPos & o) const {
      return o.row == row && o.col == col && o.rowSpan == rowSpan && o.colSpan == colSpan;
   }
};

namespace SO {
enum ModDialogOption { SpaceButtons = 1 };
Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(ModDialogOptions, ModDialogOption)
}
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(SO::ModDialogOptions)

struct ModDialogResult {
   QGridLayout *layout;
   int row;
   int colSpan;
};

ModDialogResult modDialog(QFileDialog * dialog, SO::ModDialogOptions options = {}) {
   auto *layout = qobject_cast<QGridLayout*>(dialog->layout());
   auto *fileNameLabel = dialog->findChild<QLabel*>("fileNameLabel");
   auto *fileNameEdit = dialog->findChild<QLineEdit*>("fileNameEdit");
   auto *buttonBox = dialog->findChild<QDialogButtonBox*>("buttonBox");
   auto *fileTypeLabel = dialog->findChild<QLabel*>("fileTypeLabel");
   auto *fileTypeCombo = dialog->findChild<QComboBox*>("fileTypeCombo");
   auto const buttons = buttonBox->findChildren<QPushButton*>();
   // ensure that the dialog has expected layout
   Q_ASSERT((GridPos{layout, fileNameLabel} == GridPos{2, 0, 1, 1}));
   Q_ASSERT((GridPos{layout, fileNameEdit} == GridPos{2, 1, 1, 1}));
   Q_ASSERT((GridPos{layout, buttonBox} == GridPos{2, 2, 2, 1}));
   Q_ASSERT((GridPos{layout, fileTypeLabel} == GridPos{3, 0, 1, 1}));
   Q_ASSERT((GridPos{layout, fileTypeCombo} == GridPos{3, 1, 1, 1}));
   Q_ASSERT(buttons.size() == 2);

   // remove widgets and layouts
   for (auto *w : std::initializer_list<QWidget*>{buttonBox, fileTypeLabel, fileTypeCombo})
      layout->removeWidget(w);

   // add widgets in new locations
   if (options & SO::SpaceButtons) {
      for (auto *b : buttons) b->setParent(dialog);
      buttonBox->hide();
      layout->addWidget(buttons.at(0), 2, 2, 1, 1);
      layout->addWidget(buttons.at(1), 4, 2, 1, 1);
   } else {
      layout->addWidget(buttonBox, 2, 2, 3, 1);
   }
   layout->addWidget(fileTypeLabel, 4, 0, 1, 1);
   layout->addWidget(fileTypeCombo, 4, 1, 1, 1);

   return {layout, 3, 3};
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QFileDialog dialog;
   dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);
   auto mod = modDialog(&dialog, SO::SpaceButtons);
   mod.layout->addItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 50), mod.row, 0);
   dialog.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```